# Enter absolute path, return relative path in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting relative path from absolute path in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637945/getting-relative-path-from-absolute-path-in-php)

When including PHP-Files I often use absolute paths like

```
/etc/..../index.php
```

As I don't own the server those files may not be found if the admin changes position of the files.

But trying to find the right path using

```
..
```

each time when changing files is a hassle.

Is there a function or script I can pass my

```
/etc/..../index.php
```

to for it to return the relative path I can use with include?

Comment: Please perform a search before posting. Related posts also appear whilst you're writing your question. Several of them are duplicates of yours.

Comment: At any rate, if the admin changes the position of the files, a relative path will not work. A relative path is only really useful if you want to ensure that all references are maintained when the structure is maintained but the path has changed, i.e. When moving from a test server to live.

Answer (score 1):

`dirname(__FILE__)` returns the current directory name `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))` takes you one level up etc. its the best way to include files

Comment: For readability I suggest using `dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'` instead of subsequent `dirname()`-calls. Because `.` and `..` are folders, the resulting path remains absolute. Also PHP5.3 introduces `__DIR__` as replacement for `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
__DIR__.'/../../../index.php'
```

**DIR** returns directory of the file it was called from.

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` in pre-5.3 (see @Ryans answer)

Answer (score 0):

Tomalak Geret'kal is right, there is an algorithm for you here: [Getting relative path from absolute path in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637945/getting-relative-path-from-absolute-path-in-php)

As an alternative function you can use one posted by http://iubito.free.fr in PHP manual in 2003:

```
/**
 * Return the relative path between two paths / Retourne le chemin relatif entre 2 chemins
 *
 * If $path2 is empty, get the current directory (getcwd).
 * @return string
 */
function relativePath($path1, $path2='') {
if ($path2 == '') {
    $path2 = $path1;
    $path1 = getcwd();
}

//Remove starting, ending, and double / in paths
$path1 = trim($path1,'/');
$path2 = trim($path2,'/');
while (substr_count($path1, '//')) $path1 = str_replace('//', '/', $path1);
while (substr_count($path2, '//')) $path2 = str_replace('//', '/', $path2);

//create arrays
$arr1 = explode('/', $path1);
if ($arr1 == array('')) $arr1 = array();
$arr2 = explode('/', $path2);
if ($arr2 == array('')) $arr2 = array();
$size1 = count($arr1);
$size2 = count($arr2);

//now the hard part :-p
$path='';
for($i=0; $i<min($size1,$size2); $i++)
{
    if ($arr1[$i] == $arr2[$i]) continue;
    else $path = '../'.$path.$arr2[$i].'/';
}
if ($size1 > $size2)
    for ($i = $size2; $i < $size1; $i++)
        $path = '../'.$path;
else if ($size2 > $size1)
    for ($i = $size1; $i < $size2; $i++)
        $path .= $arr2[$i].'/';

return $path;
}
```