# Getting relative path from folder

Tags: php, relative-path, absolute-path

My filemanager folder is located here:

```
localhost/cakeapp/app/webroot/js/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/filemanager/
```

In cakeapp root directory, I have two folders:

```
uploadedImages (cakeapp/uploadedImages)
UploadedImagesThumbs (cakeapp/uploadedImagesThumbs).
```

I have this situation in `config.php` File:

```
$base_url ="http://localhost";

// path from base_url to base of upload folder (with start and final /)
$upload_dir = '/cakeapp/uploadedImages/';

// relative path from filemanager folder to thumbs folder (with final /)
$thumbs_base_path = '???????/uploadedImagesThumbs'; 

// relative path from filemanager folder to upload folder (with final /)
$current_path = '???????/uploadedImages/';
```

How I get the correct relative path for `$thumbs_base_path` and `$current_path` from filemanager folder?

Comment: `$thumbs_base_path = '../../../../../../../../uploadedImagesThumbs/';`?

Comment: Thanks, it works! I did seven times '../' and not eight when I try to solved this problem.

Comment: This hardly seems like good coding...

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
function getRelativePath($from, $to) {
$patha = explode('/', $from);
$pathb = explode('/', $to);
$start_point = count(array_intersect($patha,$pathb));
while($start_point--) {
    array_shift($patha);
    array_shift($pathb);
}
$output = "";
if(($back_count = count($patha))) {
    while($back_count--) {
        $output .= "../";
    }
} else {
    $output .= './';
}
return $output . implode('/', $pathb);
}
```

Check the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637945/getting-relative-path-from-absolute-path-in-php).It has many more examples