# Referencing file from realpath PHP

Tags: php, ftp, relative-path, filepath, realpath

I have a class that handles FTP stuff located here:

```
/var/www/html/crm/rhinos/classes/ftp.php
```

This class is included in a script that generates a spreadsheet here:

```
/var/www/html/crm/send_cust_lock.php
```

The generated spreadsheet is located here:

```
/var/www/html/crm/tmp/cust_lock_1430424215.xlsx
```

My class contains the following method:

```
public function put($filepath){
    $fp = fopen($filepath, 'r');
    $z = ftp_fput($this->connection, $filepath, $fp, FTP_BINARY);
    fclose($fp);
    return $z;
}
```

From my `send_cust_lock.php` script, when I call `$ftp->put($fn);` (`$fn` being the above filepath to the spreadsheet), I get the following error:

```
Warning: ftp_fput(): Can't open that file: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/crm/rhinos/classes/ftp.php on line 62
```

`fopen()` does not throw an error, so why does `ftp_put()` throw one?

I have tried converting the path to a relative path using the function in the chosen answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637945/getting-relative-path-from-absolute-path-in-php), but no luck. How can I convert the filepath to something that `ftp_put()` can recognise?

Comment: Are you trying to FTP into the same server as the script/file already run?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, no, I'm trying to send it from my development machine to a remote server over the internet.

Comment: ok, next question, your code says `ftp_fput()` but your description mentions `ftp_put()`. Which do you need help on? `Realpath()` will return the fully resolved absolute path (as a string) to a file or false if the file could not be found. As long as that is not false, you should be able to use it with `ftp_put`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, I was so determined that the problem was with the filepath I didn't bother rereading the manual.. turns out I don't even need the filepath where I was putting it. The question has been correctly answered, thanks for you help though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fput.php) says the values are:

```
ftp_fput ( resource $ftp_stream , string $remote_file , resource $handle , int $mode [, int $startpos = 0 ] )
```

And you are passing:

```
$z = ftp_fput($this->connection, $filepath, $fp, FTP_BINARY);
```

Where your `$fp` is a handle to the local file as expected, but why are you passing the same path as the `$remote_file`? It's not going to find it on the remote FTP since you passed the local file name.