Is there a way to make RecursiveDirectoryIterator return relative paths to a wrapping iterator?
With RecursiveDirectoryIterator, I can use getSubPathname() to get the path relative to the search directory.
However, that doesn't help if I am using a RegexIterator around it to filter the filepaths.
Is there a way to make the RecursiveDirectoryIterator produce relative paths when it's iterated over?

You can see all the options here. If there's no option that does this, you can't do it.

You can include the search directory in the regexp.

See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637945/getting-relative-path-from-absolute-path-in-php/2638272#2638272 can help you solve this. You could use a Decorator or subclass the RecursiveDirectoryIterator to produce relative paths from absolute paths and then wrap that iterator in the regex iterator.
